# Visual Studio - Determining Lines No Of Lines of code in a project

Tags: visual-studio, code-metrics, lines-of-code

Visual Studio - Determining Lines No Of Lines of code in a project - is this possible in VS  2008?

Comment: "Determining Lines No Of Lines of code in a project"
What does this mean?
Do you want to find out the total number of lines you have in your project?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find [SlickEdit gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=90) SLOC report to be very good and FREE! :)

Breaks down comments/lines of code etc.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

there is no direct way from vs2008 to do it, but you can use extended tools such as:

[C# and VB.NET Line Count Utility](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/07/01/c-and-vbnet-line-count-utility/)

Answer (score 3):

TeamSuite will report this value as part of it's [code metrics](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/10/03/new-for-visual-studio-2008-code-metrics.aspx) along with other, perhaps more valuable, statistics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Project Line Counters add-ins available from from [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) -

- [Line Counter - Writing a Visual Studio 2005 & 2008 Add-In](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx)
- [Project Line Counter Add-In v2.10 for VS.NET and VC6](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/linecount.aspx)