# Visual Studio 2008 & Number of Lines in a Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you count the lines of code in a Visual Studio solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution)

Hello all,

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Resharper 4.5 but I haven't figured out how to determine the total number of lines of code in a Solution. The solution I am working on has about 12 projects. Do the tools I am using support such feature? If not, is there a utility that will do this for me ?

Thanks,
Marios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box supported way of doing this with Visual Studio.  However there are several freely available tools out there which provide this metric.  Or you could quickly code up one of the following

1. A PowerShell Script
2. A Visual Studio Macro