# Does this PowerShell code count empty lines when executed

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count the lines of code in my project. It's on a remote server, so I can't exactly install software, I can but it's not that easy and it's not worth the trouble. Trying to count my lines of code I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941444/count-code-lines-number-in-visual-studio/13214034#13214034) piece of code that works and spits out a number.

My questions is, does

```
(dir -r -include   *.cs,*.html | select-string . ).count
```

count empty lines when executed in the root project folder, or just those with anything on them ?

Comment: Seems like it'd be pretty easy for you to test & find out for yourself.

Comment: @alroc It never occurred to me but now reading it - yes, you are quite correct, thanks!

Comment: You don't even need regex to do this: `(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.cs', '*.html' | Get-Content | Where-Object {$_.Trim()}).Count`  or  `(gci -r -i *.cs, *.html | gc | ? {$_.Trim()}).Count` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

Your regex pattern: `.`, will match any **1** character, but a truly empty line has exactly **0** characters, so the answer is no.