# How to get VS.NET solution's total line count with Code Metrics in VS.NET 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, code-metrics

VS.NET 2010's Code Metric window provides line count, it doesn't show a sum of all projects in the window. When you export to Excel it lists all sub classes again therefore it's not possible to calculate the total line of code in the solution.

If you have 1-5 projects it's no problem but if you have more than 30 then it's really too much to do.

Has anyone figured out a way to do this? *I don't want to install a separate tool for this as there should be an easy way to get this out of Code Metrics window.*

Comment: submit a bug report or feature request to Microsoft Connect, and see how the developers respond, http://connect.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtering feature in Excel to filter out only row with Scope = 'Namespace'. Then you can just select all rows in the line count column and the sum appears in the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Well you may have a look at [How do you count the lines of code in a Visual Studio solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution)