# Powershell script to count number of lines ommitting a line containing a specific character

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell.

Need help in writing a script to count the total number of lines in a visual studio project provided I ommit (ignore) the commented lines in the code. Eg: <'> single quote as in vb.net. Whichever line is commented i.e begins with <'> single quote I do not need to consider in the lines count of the file.

I've been successful so far in writing the script for counting the number of lines in a project based on the file types(say *.vb etc). like below

```
(dir -include *.cs,*.xaml -recurse | select-string .).Count
```

- I now need how can I ignore the line beginning with a single quote while counting?
- Could you suggest something i can include alongwith the above code line??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
(gc c:\file.vb | ? { !$_.startswith("'") }).count
```

Edit after comment:

try this:

```
dir c:\myfolder -include *.cs,*.xaml,*.txt -Recurse | % { $count = (gc $_ |  ? { $_ -notmatch '^\s*$|^''|/\*|\*/' }).count; if ($count) {write-host "$_ `tcount: $count"} }
```

this one count no empty lines, no line starting with ' and no lines containing /* or */.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But already have code for counting no of lines in a file like above. Could you suggest something i could tag along the existing code line.

Comment: @ashishg Can you reformulate the question? In your OP you are asking for counting lines exclude lines starting with ' and all the answers provided are doing this job.

Comment: The idea was to merge your code with mine (as in OP). Can i do something like - (gc $filetypes -recurse | ? { !$_.startswith("'") } select-string .).Count? - (Here $filetypes=".vb",".asmx"..etc) I have files in multiple folders to be checked. Also I would like to check for multi-identifiers (operators) like ',/*,*/,blank line,space etc. Do not include in the count if the line contains any of these identifiers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ashishg I can't figure out why you need `select-string .`??

Comment: I refered to the example given here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution .Actually the script given by you works, the only thing I want is rather than checking for filename mentioned after gc, I want it to check the filetypes and I want it to check all file extensions in  multiple folders. But I am not sure if I can use -recurse here with gc. Also it would be great if you could help me on how to test for multiple operators.

Comment: Great!!!Thanks a lot Christian. That worked:) Just one last thing - what if I want to display the sum of all the number of lines of all the files. Eg: right now if I have 2 vb files (vb1.vb & vb2.vb) in project1, this script gives me the no of lines in each file. Like o/p - project1: 13 15.. what if I want it to display the sume i.e, as 28? Thanks!

Comment: `(dir c:\myfolder -include *.VB -Recurse | % { (gc $_ |  ? { $_ -notmatch '^\s*$|^''|/\*|\*/' }).coUNT} | Measure-Obje
ct -Sum).sum`  work on this...

Comment: Thanks a ton christian.. this works! Was having a tough time trying this:) Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to sort by the count in descending order?

Answer (score 1):

Get all lines that do not start with a single quote, even if there's a leading space or tab in front of it. Pipe the result to the `Measure-Object` to count lines.

```
Get-Content file.ext | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "(\s?)+'"} | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But already have code for counting no of lines in a file like above. Could you suggest something i could tag along the existing code line for my requirement.