# How to find out how many lines of code have been written in a .Net project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This might sound useless and has nothing to do with code quality, but just for the sake of information (and for fun to be honest :) )

Is there a way to retrieve in Visual Studio the amount of lines written in any kind of .Net project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution

Comment: It was indeed already asked, sorry about that

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/625710/Line-Counting-Trickery-within-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean , hope it helps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165340.aspx

Comment: This is the line numbering in the editor. I was in fact talking about getting the amount of lines on the project itself. Answer has been posted in the question comments.