# Counting lines of code for xaml and sql files in Visual Studio project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, lines-of-code

I have used Analyze toolbar-> Calculate metrics in Visual Studio to count lines in whole of the solution. It only counts C# code, it doesn't take .xaml,.xaml.cs and .sql files into consideration.
Is there any tool or Add-in that would help me in counting lines from all of these files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution. Check out answer by @Greg D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CLOC](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) (Count Lines of Code) program to count lines. It's command line program but it's very simple to using.

```
Usage: cloc [options] <file(s)/dir(s)>
```

CLOC options you can find [here](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc#options-).

If you want to count lines in the entire solution you should invoke `cloc` with following parameters:

```
cloc "path_to_solution_directory"
```