# How to count lines of code in a PHP project?

Tags: php, git, lines-of-code

I'd like to count the the lines of code of a PHP-project in a given git repository. Currently I'm using:

```
git ls-files -- *.php* | xargs wc -l
```

to count the lines of code in all php files.

It would be great to have a step before counting all lines, that skips all empty lines and maybe also lines containing comments (in PHP this in `#` and `//` for single line comments and `/* */` for multiline comments). I guess `sed` might help, but how to handle multiline comments?

Comment: If counting the lines of code is important, use [phploc](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc)

Comment: Just out of curiosity what are you using the line count for?

Comment: @cmorrissey - let's hope it isn't for measuring productivity

Comment: @MarkBaker my thoughts exactly

Comment: @cmorrissey: I'm refactoring an old project. I try to remove unnecessary stuff and increase documentation. Therefore I'd like to exclude empty lines and have a measurement with and without documentation.

Comment: You might want to consider a few other tools for measuring progress, rather than a simplistic line count - http://phpqatools.org/ - lists a range of useful tools when refactoring and documenting code

Comment: @MarkBaker: Could you write an answer from you questions, so that I can accept I,...

Comment: Another one I've had to use which I thought was good -> http://cloc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You may use [powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731851%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) for this as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution). Open Powershell and go to the directory with your PHP-files. Issue the following command:

```
(dir -include *.php -recurse | select-string .).Count
```

If you want files of other file types to be included, simply add them like

```
(dir -include *.php, *.js -recurse | select-string .).Count
```

If there aren't any subdirectories, the command would be

```
(dir *.php | select-string .).Count
```

Comment: I'm not a Powershell user, so apologies if this is wrong, but doesn't the fact that the question references `wc` and `sed` imply that @Edward is not a Windows user?

Comment: Developing on Windows so I found it useful. Thanks