# VS Code - Is there a way to calculate all the lines of code in a project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there native functionality or a recommended extension to get the number of lines of code in a project/workspace or folder in VS Code?

I found this older post below for for VS 2010 & 2013 using Analyze --> Calculate Code Metrics as native functionality. I'm looking at extensions that might do this as well. Also, I am using a specific theme I like (Dracula Official) so I'd prefer not to have to add another theme if possible.

[VS 2010 & 2013 Analze -> Calculate Code Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244729/how-do-you-count-the-lines-of-code-in-a-visual-studio-solution#:%7E:text=Change%20the%20search%20option%20to,the%20lines%20of%20code%20count.%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

check this extension for vscode counting lines of code in a particular directory, workspace and provides many other feature as well.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uctakeoff.vscode-counter

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was after.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad....actually running linux devcontainer so this is extremely helpful.   Looking it up, the syntax is `wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...`  and returns 'number of lines, word count, byte and characters count'    Seems like you have to specify files so not been able to get it working on a folder.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's not VSCode specific, but there is **[cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)** that flexibly does code line counts from the command line for several languages, and is easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to open a Git bash shell in the terminal in Windows, or a zsh shell in MacOS and type the following command from the eighties:

```
find src -name \*.java | xargs wc -l
```

this is for a Java project, modify according to taste.
If your Java project has a Maven structure, you can distinguish between

```
find src/main -name \*.java | xargs wc -l
```

and

```
find src/test -name \*.java | xargs wc -l
```